# Does a USB modem have its own MAC Address?

Tags: usb, modem, mac-address

My USB modem is now showing its MAC address in ipconfig /all.
So does that mean that a USB modem has its own MAC address?

Comment: A single question mark is sufficient.

Comment: Given the first revision, I'm not sure if *now showing* shouldn't read *not showing* instead?

Comment: @sahil, please "associate" your accounts at http://serverfault.com/users/38218?tab=accounts, after which you'll be the owner of the above question again. Next, please edit the question to make clear if `ipconfig` does, or does NOT, show any MAC address. (And just like I commented on Server Fault, see also http://superuser.com/faq)

Answer (score 2):

Your dial up analogue USB modem probably does not have a MAC address - it doesn't do Ethernet, it connected to your PC using a Com port, hence it has no need for a MAC address.

Your ADSL USB modem may have a MAC address as it may connect to your PC using a virtual Ethernet interface, hence it needs a MAC address.

Lets face it - if ipconfig /all shows a MAC address it's safe to say it has one...